# Is it possible to use 'if constexpr' to determine if a template function could be instantiated with a particular type parameter?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae, if-constexpr

Suppose there exists the following code:

```cpp
class Foo {
 public:
    void foo() const { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
};

class Bar {
 public:
    void bar() const { std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; }
}; 

template <typename T>
void DoFoo(const T& f) {
    f.foo();
}
```

I want to write a function like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void DoFooIfPossible() {
    if constexpr (/* DoFoo<T>(T()) would compile */) {
        DoFoo(T());
    } else {
        std::cout << "[not possible]" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

So that:

```cpp
int main() {
    DoFooIfPossible<Foo>();
    DoFooIfPossible<Bar>();
}
```

compiles and prints:

```
foo
[not possible]
```

I know that **for this particular example** I can implement this in the following way by detecting the presence of the member function that `DoFoo` uses:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct IsFooPossible : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct IsFooPossible<
    T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&T::foo)>>> 
    : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
void DoFooIfPossible() {
    if constexpr (IsFooPossible<T>::value) {
        DoFoo(T());
    } else {
        std::cout << "[not possible]" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, the question I am asking here is: **Can I implement this without making any assumptions about the implementation of `DoFoo`?**.

In a real-world scenario, `DoFoo` may be a library function that I do not own. It may place many different conditions on its template parameter type `T`, and those conditions may change over time. So replicating those conditions in an `enable_if` expression in my code is not a viable solution.

I was wondering if it is possible to write my `if constexpr` expression in a way that *directly* tests whether `DoFoo<T>` can be instantiated without having any special knowledge of the implementation of `DoFoo`, and without modifying `DoFoo`.

I'm trying to do this in C++17, so if there's something in C++20 that could handle this, that would be interesting to know but wouldn't solve my problem.

(Also note that for the sake of creating a minimal example, I'm assuming `T` is default-constructable. I don't really care about the `T()` part of `DoFoo(T())` -- I'm trying to determine if `DoFoo<T>` can be instantiated at all.)

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7102b8ea7114b29c)?

Comment: @Coal, thanks, but that depends on modifying the signature of the function I'm trying to test (`DoFoo` in my example, `call_f` in yours). I need to treat that as immutable and write a test for it as-is.

Comment: You are probably looking for [`std::is_invokable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) instead of `std::is_member_function_pointer_v`. Or maybe the [`std::invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable) concept in C++20.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a way to use `std::is_invocable` to test whether `DoFoo<T>` can be invoked, without causing a compile error in the case where `DoFoo<T>` cannot be instantiated? (Testing whether `T::foo` is invocable doesn't help, since in reality I'm trying to get rid of any and all assumptions about what the implementation of`DoFoo` requires of `T`)

Comment: I don't think that you can ask the compiler in a generic way "will *this specialization* compile?" Rather, you have to ask the compiler for the specific preconditions under which it will compile *this specialization*.

Answer (score 2):

The ultimate solution would be C++20 `concept`s, because old-school SFINAE methods have their caveats. However there are still compiler bugs that might hunt you down.
You can use a `requires` clause as an inline concept which can finally evaluate a `constexpr bool`:

```
if constexpr(
    requires {
        /*do your test declaration s*/
    }
)//...rest
```